# How to preserve parameter names for debug?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin

I need to subclass java files (of my IntelliJ java project, so I have the source) in Kotlin, but they just implement abstract methods using p0, p1, etc. for variable names.

So I think I must turn on debug info, but in my IJ IDE debug info is already on.

What else must I do to preserve parameter names for classes, interfaces, etc.?

Comment: do you implement your java interface or is it some interface from 3rd party library?

Comment: it is all my code, just in a separate java only project

Comment: It's quite strange. If you have both projects opened as 1 intellij projects then it should see and understand the sources, otherwise you can connect the sources so it can see full signatures...

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing with the Android SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you see is [a bug in Kotlin 1.0](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11039) which will be fixed in the 1.0.1 update.